# Disable CSRF protection for Ajax Calls - How bad is it?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

Guys I'm running into a lot of trouble with CSRF and ajax calls in Laravel 5.

I am sending the X-CSRF token with every ajax call in the header, as explained here: http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token

The problem is, randomly, the token cannot be verified, and I end up with the following error:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:
```

It happens eventually, in 1 out of 10 calls, but still makes my application behave badly, since it's very dependant on these ajax calls.

So I posted here about the problem, but the best response I got was to "disable CSRF".

I have 2 questions about it:

1) Will disable CSRF for ajax calls make my website vulnerable?

and

2) Is there another way I can protect, if I find no other way but disable CSRF?

Comment: If you disable the CSRF verificacion for ajax calls, your server gonna allow external pettitions, like a web service, or web api; so if anyone knows the url and the variables he can call an ajax request to your server, and your server gonna allow it; thats all, if you don't care about this, maybe you'll not have any problems.

Comment: Well, my code is checking if the user who made the ajax calls has rights to do the actions he wants, and if he is logged in, I guess he can send the call however he wants.. so I should be ok, right? Is there any type of abuse that can be generated from that? Perhaps spammers or attacks?

Comment: @CarlosHerreraPlata maybe have some mistake. CSRF attacks based on user session. You can not fake session only with url. In most of case, There is no real risk with ajax because all of modern browsers prevent ajax cross domain. Except you force allow `Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest` to allow ajax cross domain.

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind XSS attacks is that other sites trick your users into performing actions on your application using their session.

There are many types of XSS attacks out there. The following is just a simple example of one type that may happen.

So, imagine you have an admin route for deleting your website: `/self-destruct`. Now, imagine that you are logged into your website as admin. You have access to the route, but you would never go to it by accident.

Now, the idea is that as your browsing the web, you come along a malicious site that, for some reason or another, redirects your browser to your `/self-destruct` route on your application.

**With CSRF protection:** the malicious site doesn't have a proper CSRF token to give to you to pass along to your route. Since your route requires a proper CSRF token, you'll get a `TokenMismatchException` error and your website is fine.

**Without CSRF protection:** the malicious site doesn't need anything extra. They have redirected you, a logged in admin user, to your admin self destruct route. Your website is now gone.

Security is always a balance act. If you don't think there is any risk to XSS attacks on your website, then don't worry about it. If you're developing a banking application and you don't want an XSS attack to be able to transfer all the funds of any susceptible user to an offshore banking account, then CSRF would be a good idea.

Comment: Good example. I was thinking more along the lines of "a website redirects to a stock purchase link on a site you are logged into". In other words you end up purchasing stock you never intended to. And you have no idea how it happened. Other examples would be email forms, or social media post spam.

Comment: Probably you may increase the session timeout in session config, it'll improve it a little tho. Another possible way could be to fetching/refreshing the csrf by ajax after an interval.

Comment: @The Alpha is it possible that I'm generating multiple sessions for the same user? I managed to debug the token comparison, and sometimes it's different from the one being sent with the ajax call.. Some times it changes twice in like 2 minutes.. My session lifetime in laravel config is set to 120

Comment: What's wrong with that? Btw, there will be only one at a time, token will update both sides if you do that.